# JAR execution is not accepting required arguments for Walmart Developer API authentication

Tags: java, jar, walmart-api

Walmart Developers API provides a JAR files to assist with authentication for their API, which requires you to enter the entire GET URL with all arguments.

The JAR download & information about the JAR executable can be found here: 
https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/contentProvider

Information about the API call we are attempting is found on "All Orders" here:
https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace

If I am using only 1 argument, the command is working perfectly. But if it requires more than 1 argument, I am getting errors.

Here is an example URL that IS WORKING:
https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders?createdStartDate=2016-08-16T10:30:30.155Z

Here is an example URL that is NOT WORKING: 
https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/orders?createdStartDate=2016-08-16T10:30:30.155Z&status=Acknowledged

If I use the above the JAR throws the error:

'status' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It is not just the "status" argument, but if I try to use ANY arguments at all, it does not accept them with this error.

I thought I may just need to escape the string before the "&", I attempted "\&" and "/&", but that does not seem to work either. I am not sure how to add the argument in a way the JAR file will accept it.

The most frustrating thing about this, is that the documentation for the JAR file specifically states "The full URL you wish to call, including any path and query parameters". Yet if you include the parameters, it errors?

Any advice on how I could move forward with this JAR file?

Thanks

Comment: That error message seems to come from the Windows CMD console, you haven't "executed" the JAR yet.

Comment: Try put quotation marks around your URL, like this "https://.../..."

Comment: Luke Lee's suggestion was the one to work! Thank you!

Comment: @xiaofeng.li @ndrosos Did `^&` really solved the issue for you? We tried it but it doesn't work. Still getting the same error. We're using the JAR file provided by Walmart for their version 3 API:

`not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
  at com.walmart.services.partner.digitalsignutil.DigitalSignatureUtil.main(DigitalSignatureUtil.java:33)`

Answer (score 0):

To escape the "&" character, try `^&`. See [Quotes, Escape Characters ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

P.S. I'm on Linux so couldn't really verify this.